# InfoWindow not Displaying

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I'm trying to have this so that someone clicks on the map, and an infoWindow pops up telling them that latlng. For now, just trying to figure out how to get an infoWindow to come up. I found a similar problem here with markers and edited the function a bit but I'm missing something which I'm sure is simple and I just cannot pin point. Here's the code:

```
        function InfoWindow(location) {
          if ( marker ) {
            marker.setPosition(location);
          } else {
            marker = new google.maps.infoWindow({
              position: location,
              content: "sam"
            });
          }
        }

        google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
          InfoWindow(event.latLng);
        });
                }
```

Help greatly appreciated!
Thanks

Comment: See my answer in your other post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671571/google-maps-api-v3-info-bubble/11671897#11671897

Answer (score 0):

I am using InfoBubble, it appears better than InfoWindow and it can also be handled easier. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Event is a LatLng

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
      InfoWindow(event);
    });
```

Comment: thanks, will try this
Edit: did this, thanks for the heads up. Still no infowindow popping up though

Comment: you need to invoke the open method of the InfoWindows
marker.open(map);

Comment: Event is not a LatLng, it has a latLng property however.

Answer (score 0):

You were correct in passing the LatLng of the event (event.latLng), not the whole event. To help with the output, I included code that splits the lat and lng up into strings. A couple other things I fixed: needs to be a capital "I" in google.maps.InfoWindow; set the content to new latLng if the window already exists; added the code to actually open the window at the end. This should take care of everything for ya

```
function InfoWindow(location) {
    var lat = location.lat().toString();
    var lng = location.lng().toString();
    var new_content = "Lat: " + lat + "<br />Long: " + lng
  if ( marker ) {
    marker.setPosition(location);
    marker.setContent(new_content);
  } else {
      marker = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
      position: location,
      content: new_content
    });
  }
  marker.open(map);
}

google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
  InfoWindow(event.latLng);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The [Map MouseEvent](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MouseEvent) has a latLng property

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) 
{
   new google.maps.InfoWindow({
              map:map, 
              content:"coordinates:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue(),
              position:event.latLng});});
}
```

"map" is a reference to your google.maps.Map.

Tested on [this map](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_MW_example_map1.html) by pasting this into the address bar, then clicking on the map:

```
javascript:google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {new google.maps.InfoWindow({map:map, content:"coordinates:"+event.latLng.toUrlValue(),position:event.latLng});});
```